# CURL - [NULL Response] In Codeigniter

Tags: php, curl, codeigniter-3

I want to fetch data from Third_party API called BirdEye. I was using Core PHP Inbuilt Functions of CURL to fetch data, it was working fine, Now When I switched to Library I am bit confused because it doesn't gives me any response in return.

I have Downloaded Curl Libray from Here : [Curl Library Download and Example](https://www.formget.com/curl-library-codeigniter/)

I tried to create a demo just to check my Library is working fine or not, it worked. Now If I fetch data from Bird-Eye Api I don't know It gives me nothing in response.
My Code is here:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {
public function index()
    {
        $this->load->library('curl');

//  Setting URL To Fetch Data From
$this->curl->create('https://api.birdeye.com/resources/v1/business/147802929307762?api_key=ApiKeyGoesHere');

//  To Temporarily Store Data Received From Server
$this->curl->option('buffersize', 10);

//  To support Different Browsers
$this->curl->option('useragent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.8) Gecko/20100722 Firefox/3.6.8 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)');

//  To Receive Data Returned From Server
$this->curl->option('returntransfer', 1);

//  To follow The URL Provided For Website
$this->curl->option('followlocation', 1);

//  To Retrieve Server Related Data
$this->curl->option('HEADER', true);

//  To Set Time For Process Timeout
$this->curl->option('connecttimeout', 600);

//  To Execute 'option' Array Into cURL Library & Store Returned Data Into $data
$data = $this->curl->execute();
//  To Display Returned Data
echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }
}
```

I don't know where I am going wrong I am passing all the required parameters to the Api.
Link to Api Documentation is : [Link to BirdEye Api Documentation](http://docs.birdeye.apiary.io/#reference/business/get/get-business)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the header here in your curl request.because as per the api the response would be in the `json` format.

```
    $this->load->library('curl');
    $get_url ="https://api.birdeye.com/resources/v1/customer/all?businessId=147802929307762&api_key=YOURAPIKEY"; 
    $result=$this->curl->simple_get($get_url, false, array(CURLOPT_USERAGENT => true, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE, CURLOPT_HEADER => FALSE, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array("Content-Type: application/json", "Accept: application/json"))); 
    $result=json_decode($result);
    echo '<pre>'; print_r($result);
```

Here i have also passed the headers with the curl request.

P.S. the code is not tested but it should work !!!!

Comment: Don't forget to add *CURLOPT_TIMEOUT* in curl request